# Prove: If $f'(a)=0$, $f'\gt 0$ in some interval left of $a$, and $f'<0$ in some interval right of $a$, then $x$ is a local maximum point.

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

In Spivak's *Calculus*, the Chapter 11 exposition makes the following claim without a formal proof:

> If $a$ is a critical point of $f$ (i.e. $f'(a)=0$), $f'\gt 0$ in some interval to the left of $a$, and $f'<0$ in some interval to the right of $a$, then $a$ is a local maximum point.

In this book, a local maximum point is defined as:

> Let $f$ be a function and $A$ a set of numbers contained in the domain of $f$. A point $a$ in $A$ is a **local maximum** [minimum] **point** for $f$ on $A$ if there is some $\delta \gt 0$ such that $a$ is a maximum [minimum] point for $f$ on $A \ \cap \ (a-\delta,  a+\delta)$

Spivak then provides the classic picture of an upside down parabolic-shaped segment where the point $a$ is drawn as the **maximum point** and $f(a)$ the **maximum value** attained along the parabolic curve (in order to show that the above claim has validity).

Without referencing Spivak's illustration, it is not immediately apparent to me that the point $a$ is, in fact, a local maximum point. In this post, I want to prove Spivak's claim by demonstrating that, given the assumptions:

> $f(a)$ is the least upper bound in some neighborhood around $a$.

I think the logic is correct, but I wanted to make sure I did not overlook anything...in particular, how I defined my intervals.

---

Let $I_L$ and $I_R$ represent the left and right intervals, respectively, where $f'$ at any $x \in I_L$ is greater than $0$ and for any $x \in I_R$, $f'(x)<0$. $I_L$ can be viewed as an open interval of the form $(a-\delta_L, a)$ and $I_R$ viewed as $(a, a+\delta_R)$, for $\delta_L,\delta_R \gt 0$. The argument will work for $I_L= [a-\delta_L, a)$ and $I_R=(a, a+\delta_R]$ as well. It follows that $f$ is strictly increasing on $I_L$ and that $f$ is strictly decreasing on $I_R$.  Next, because $f$ is differentiable at $a$, we know that $f$ is continuous at $a$.

Consider the following set $S=\left\{s: s \in I_L \cup I_R \cup \{a\} \right\}$, or equivalently $S=\left\{s: s \in (a-\delta_L,a+\delta_R)\right\}$. Next, consider the set $T=\{f(s):s\in S\}$. To show that $f(a)$ is the least upper bound of $T$, we need to *first* show that it is an upper bound of $T$ and then *second* show that for any $\varepsilon \gt 0$, there is some $t \in T$ such that $f(a)-t \lt \varepsilon$.

---

Prove: $f(a)$ **is an upper bound of $T$** - show that for any $t \in T$, $f(a) \geq t$

Let $x^*$ be an arbitrary element in $S$. If $x^*=a$, then clearly $f(a) \geq f(x^*)$. So consider if $x^* \in I_L$ or $x^* \in I_R$. Assume the former.

By trichotomy of $\mathbb R$, $f(x^*) \lt f(a)$ or $f(x^*) = f(a)$ or $f(x^*) \gt f(a)$. Suppose $f(x^*) \gt f(a)$. Consider  a $\varepsilon^*=f(x^*)-f(a)\gt 0$. By continuity of $f$ at $a$, we know that $f$ is **left continuous** at $a$. Therefore, we have some $\delta_{\varepsilon^*}$ such that for any $z$: $0 \leq a-z \lt \delta_{\varepsilon^*} \rightarrow |f(z) -f(a)| \lt \varepsilon^*= f(x^*)-f(a)$.

Next, consider the distance $\delta'=\frac{|a-x^*|}{2}$ and the corresponding interval $(a-\delta',a)$. Notice that $(a-\delta',a) \subset I_L$.  Let $\delta^*=\min(\delta_{\varepsilon^*},\delta')$. Then we can say that for any $z$: $0 \leq a-z \lt \delta^* \rightarrow |f(z)-f(a)|\lt f(x^*)-f(a)$. Choosing an arbitrary $z^*$ that satisfies these conditions, we have: $|f(z^*)-f(a)| \lt f(x^*)-f(a) \implies f(z^*)\lt f(x^*)$. However, our definition of $\delta^*$ (because of $\delta'$) forces $z^* \gt x^*$, but $z^* \in I_L$, which, by assumption of a strictly increasing interval, means $f(z^*) \gt f(x^*)$. This is a contradiction. A similar argument that uses **right continuity** at $a$ where $x^* \in I_R$ will show that if we assume $f(x^*) \gt f(a)$, a contradiction will arise. Therefore, for any $s \in S$, we have that $f(s) \leq f(a)$, which means that $f(a)$ is an upper bound of $T$.

---

Prove: $f(a)$ **is the least upper bound of** $T$ - show that for any $\varepsilon \gt 0$, there is some $t \in T$ such that $f(a)-t \lt \varepsilon$.

By continuity of $f$ at $a$, we know that for any $\varepsilon$, there is a corresponding $\delta_{\varepsilon}$ such that for any $x$: $0 \leq |x-a| \lt \delta_{\varepsilon} \rightarrow |f(a)-f(x)|\lt \varepsilon$. Recall our definitions of $I_L$ and $I_R$, which made use of $\delta_L$ and $\delta_R$, respectively. Consider $\delta_S=\min(\delta_L, \delta_R)$. Next let $\delta=\min(\delta_{\varepsilon},\delta_S)$.

From continuity and our first proof, we know that for any $x$: $0 \leq |x-a| \lt \delta \rightarrow |f(a)-f(x)|=f(a)-f(x)\lt \varepsilon$. By our definition of $\delta$, these $x$ are guaranteed to be within $S$ (which means any corresponding $f(x)$ is an element of $T$) and are guaranteed to satisfy the condition that $f(a)-f(x) \lt \varepsilon$. Therefore, choosing any such $x$ within this interval will do the trick, which means that $f(a)$ is the least upper bound of $T$.

---

Placing all of this in the context of the definition of "local maximum point", let $A = \text{dom}(f)$ and let $\delta=\min(\delta_L,\delta_R)$. Then $a$ is a local maximum point for $f$ on $A \cap (a-\delta, a+\delta)$.

Comment: I am not sure the claim is true.

Comment: @Moti what counter example do you have in mind.

Comment: This should show that $f(a)$ is not only the supremum, but the (unique) local maximum, a stronger result.

Comment: @Ben I think my approach could have been slightly altered to also yield the uniqueness condition. When I applied trichotomy, I only showed that for $x\neq a$, $f(x) \gt f(a)$ yields a contradiction. However, I could have also shown that for $x \neq a$, $f(x)=f(a)$  leads to a contradiction...therefore, rather than concluding with $f(x) \leq f(a)$, I would have had for $x\neq a$, $f(x) \lt f(a)$. Of course, this would have made the proof even longer. Your mean value theorem approach is likely shorter. Please feel free to post it!

Comment: I believe you can simplify the argument. For example, if we apply the Mean Value Theorem to any points in the left interval, and to $a$ we can show that $f(a)$ is greater than the value of $f$ on $I_L$. Similarly for the right interval.

Comment: @Ben solid! Cheers~

Comment: @ S.Cramer It's good you were bothered by Spivak's hand waviness here. Notice that, given an open interval where $f'>0$, if $f$ is continuous at the end points, then the MVT lets us include those end points in the region where $f$ is strictly increasing. This, even if $f'\not\gt 0$ at the end points. (And similarly for decreasing $f$)

Comment: I think I mostly follow your proof and subsequent adjustment to rule out $x = a$. The gist, if I follow is, taking the left interval, if there is any $x$ in $I_L$ with $f(x) \ge f(a)$, then there's a $y$ in $(x,a)$ with $f(y) > f(a)$. Setting $\varepsilon = \frac{f(y) - f(a)}{2}$ and using continuity of $f$ we see as we creep past $y$ towards $a$, that we'll never have $|f(z) - f(a)| < \varepsilon$ for any $z$ in $(y,a)$, which is a contradiction. Likewise for the RHS. I like it!

Comment: @Ben I think if the only assumptions were: continuity of $f$ at $a$, strictly increasing interval to the left, and strictly decreasing interval to the right, this seems to be a good approach. However, with the extra information about differentiability on the table, your method is clearly the expedited approach lol. And, yes, your interpretation is the correct gist of things - I'm leveraging the convergence behavior of continuity. Basically, the "location" of $f(a)$ in relation to the values in the left and right interval is the only location that works!

Comment: How about a local minima at "a" while there are two other local maxima on both sides of a? Why this is excluded based on the statement by Spivak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If $a$ is a critical point of $f$ (i.e. $f'(a)=0$), $f'>0$ in some interval to the left of $a$, and $f'<0$ in some interval to the right of $a$, then $a$ is a local maximum point.

Note first, I've corrected Spivak's typo (your quote says "then $x$[sic] is a local maximum point."

Here's a more direct proof using the MVT, as sketched out in my comment.

Let $x$ be any point in the left interval.

Applying the MVT we see
$$\frac{f(a) - f(x)}{a-x} = f'(x_0),$$
where $x_0$ is a point between $x$ and $a$.

Since $x_0$ is also in the left interval, $f'(x_0) > 0$, and we have

$$\frac{f(a) - f(x)}{a-x} > 0.$$

The denominator here is greater than zero. Therefore, we must have
$$f(a) - f(x) > 0,$$
or
$$f(a) > f(x).$$

This applies to all $x$ in the left interval.

A similar argument will show $f(a) > f(x)$ for all $x$ in the right interval.
$$\blacksquare$$

Comment: Whoops. Good catch - it's actually *my* typo.

Answer (score 1):

Another argument, similar to yours:
Suppose we have
$$ x_L < a < x_R,$$
with $f'(a) = 0$, $f'> 0$ on $(x_L,a)$, and $f'< 0$ on $(a,x_R)$, and $f$ is continuous on $[x_L,x_R]$.

Since $f$ is continuous on $[x_L,x_R]$, it is bound on this interval, and there exists some point $y$ in $[x_L,x_R]$ such that $f(y) \geq f(x)$ for all $x$ on $[x_L,x_R]$.

Suppose $y$, this maximum point, is in the left interval. Since $f$ is increasing to the right of $y$, immediately we have a contradiction, with $f(y) < f(x)$ for all $x$ on $(y,a)$.

In other words, $y$ cannot be on the left interval.

Similarly, $y$ cannot be on the right interval, as this is immediately contradicted by points on $(a,y)$.

Therefore, the only remaining possibility is $y = a$.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: Aside: The above proof omits a tacit appeal to MVT. MVT is how we know that $f' > 0$ [$<0$] on some open interval $(c,d) \implies f$ increasing [decreasing] on $(c,d)$. The "MVT only" proof extends this argument to the point $a$.

Answer (score 1):

One more alternative view:

We begin just as we did in my second proof:

Suppose we have
$$ x_L < a < x_R,$$
with $f'(a) = 0$, $f'> 0$ on $(x_L,a)$, and $f'< 0$ on $(a,x_R)$, and $f$ is continuous on $[x_L,x_R]$.

Again, since $f$ is continuous on $[x_L,x_R]$, it is bound on this interval, and there exists at least one point $y$ in $[x_L,x_R]$ such that $f(y) \geq f(x)$ for all $x$ on $[x_L,x_R]$.

$y$ is a maximum point of $f$ on $[x_L,x_R]$.

Since $f$ is increasing to the right of $x_L$, this point cannot be a maximum point ($y\neq x_L$.)

Since $f$ is decreasing to the left of $x_R$, this point cannot be a maximum point.

Thus, neither endpoint is a maximum point for $f$ on $[x_L,x_R]$. Therefore, at least one maximum point must be in  $(x_L,x_R)$.

Since $f$ is differentiable everywhere on $(x_L,x_R)$, we know $f'$ exists at all such maximum points, and so $f'= 0$ at all such points. As $a$ is the only such point with $f'= 0$, $a$ must a maximum point for $f$ on $[x_L,x_R]$. Not only that, but $a$ is the *only* maximum point.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: This is making use of Spivak's claim on page 190 - which states that maximum/minimum points for $f$ on a closed interval $[a,b]$ occur at either the end points $a$ or $b$, the critical points of $f$ on $ [a,b]$, or the point $x$ in $[a,b]$ such that $f$ is not differentiable at $x$.